# How to get any component's props types?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there any typescript *built-in* way to get any component's (**both** class or functional) props types? I have been looking for an answer on SO and on the official [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home.html), in vain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is the following, which seems to work:

```js
import React from "react";

// My solution
type Props<C> = C extends ComponentType<infer P> ? P : never;

class MyClassComponent extends React.Component<{ classProp1: string, classProp2: number }> { }
const MyFuncComponent: React.FunctionComponent<{ funcProp1: boolean, funcProp2: string }> = () => <></>;

type MyClassProps = Props<typeof MyClassComponent>; // { classProp1: string; classProp2: number; }
type MyFuncProps = Props<typeof MyFuncComponent>; // { funcProp1: boolean; funcProp2: string; }
```

If there is no built-in way to do so, I will make a suggestion to the Github project.
In the mean time, please feel free to improve my way of doing it.